# Siunitx and dcolumn not working in revtex4

Tags: siunitx, revtex, dcolumn

The title pretty much says it all.  I am writing up a paper that needs to be in revtex4, but for some reason both the siunitx and dcolumn packages are not working correctly.  If I comment out my document class and go with article, everything is fine.  Furthermore, the units from siunitx work in revtex4, just not the number column align.

The example below works for me, but when I comment out the article class and go with revtex4, I get errors starting with the warning: Column d is already defined on input line 8, then \inaccessible on line 16.

```
%\documentclass[aps, superscriptaddress, twocolumn, nofootinbib]{revtex4}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Here are units that work \si{\micro\metre\joule}.

Example using S tab

\begin{tabular}{S[tabformat=3.2]}% syntax for siunitx v2; for v1 use "tabformat"
555 \\
7.77 \\
99.9
\end{tabular}

Example using d tab

\begin{tabular}{d{3.2}}
555 \\
7.77 \\
99.9
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I can't be the first to have this issue with revtex4, so I'm open to suggestions to fix my problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It should be `table-format` and not `tabformat`.

Comment: @egreg Well, `tabformat` is v1 syntax :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `table-format` (`tabformat` is no longer valid and nobody should use `siunitx` version 1).

For `dcolumn`, you get the warning

```
Package array Warning: Column d is already defined
```

which is self-explaining. On the other hand, this doesn't happen with `revtex4-1`, which is the current version.

```
\documentclass[aps, superscriptaddress, twocolumn, nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Here are units that work \si{\micro\metre\joule}.

Example using S tab

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.2]}
555 \\
7.77 \\
99.9
\end{tabular}

Example using d tab

\begin{tabular}{d{3.2}}
555 \\
7.77 \\
99.9
\end{tabular}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need `revtex4`, then change the name for the new column type, say

```
\newcolumntype{e}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
```

and then use

```
\begin{tabular}{e{3.2}}
```

Comment: The `d` column seems to be defined by [`revtex4`](https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4) but not by [`revtex4-1`](https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1).

Comment: @DaiBowen Indeed! Thanks, I fixed the answer.